# How to solve this using computer.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, numerical-methods, linear-programming

Given $B = \begin{pmatrix}
  0.3 & 0 \\
  0 & 0.4 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$, and $\pi = \begin{pmatrix}0.4\\0.6\end{pmatrix} $, I need to find the elements of the stochastic matrix (the rows sum to 1) $A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} \\
  \end{pmatrix}$, which satisfies the following inequality :

$\frac{BA^{T}\pi}{1^{T}BA^{T}\pi}$ $\le$ $\pi$.

Here $1^{T}$ is a row vector of ones. So the denominator of the LHS is a scalar. The inequality should hold component wise.

There can be many solutions, I need only one. I need to do this for higher dimensional matrices, so writing out the inequalities would not be feasible.
Thanks.

Comment: What does the notation in your inequality mean? I see a ratio of matrices, and an inequality of matrices, neither of which makes sense to me offhand. Can you explain the notation?

Comment: @MPW: The denominator of the LHS is a scalar, so I'm guessing that the expression says that $LHS\leq RHS$ component-wise.

Comment: @ MPW : Sorry to have not clarified that. It is as what @Kim said.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. I assumed $1^T$ was identity matrix, so you can see where I was confused. I thought the inequality might be componentwise. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: One more thing: does $A$ have row sums $1$, column sums $1$, or both?

Comment: @ MPW : Only the rows sum to 1.